# Angular/Spring Boot, use multiple parameter in post request

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I wanna create a file uploader. For this, I want to create a folder with the name of the token and all images. The file upload works and also creating a new folder.
Without the token, it works. I just send a FormData. But when I want to add the token, it doesn't work anymore. In Postman it works with two parameters.

In spring boot I get the following error message: Current request is not a multipart request

**Angular**

```
  public uploadImage(formData: FormData, token: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + "/upload", {"formData": formData, "token": token});
  }
```

**Spring Boot**

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, String token) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(DIRECTORY.concat(token));
        if (! directory.exists()){
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : multipartFiles) {
            String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY.concat(token), filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
    }    @PostMapping("/upload")
```

Comment: How do you construct formData?

Comment: formData.append('files', file, file.name);

Comment: Right.. so add another formData.append to add the token..?

Comment: Cool. Goodluck and happy coding.